# Strange code in an attribute creating a Google Maps shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm creating a shortcode that outputs the javascript code to create a customized Google Map, like this:

```
[map w="600" h="400" style="full" z="16" marker="yes" infowindow="<h2>Title</h2>" address="New York"]
```

Here are some extracts of the code:

```
function gmap($atts) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(   
        [...]
        'infowindow' => '',
        [...]
        'style' => ''       
    ), $atts);

    [...]

    //infowindow

    if($atts['infowindow'] != '') 
    {
        $thiscontent = htmlspecialchars_decode($atts['infowindow']);
        $returncode .= '
        var contentString = \'' . $thiscontent . '\';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        ';
    }

    [...]

    return $returncode;
}
```

Everything is fine if in "infowindow" I only use text, but if I use markup, like `<h2>Title</h2>` what I get in the code is:

```
var contentString = '<br />
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>';
```

... with two newlines that mess up the js.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're getting screwed over by WordPress's automatic paragraph formatting.

**Option 1:** Sometimes you can get around this by switching to the html tab of the editor, then removing any whitespace in your markup, but this also has a tendency to fall apart next time you edit the same page/post.

**Option 2:** Disable wpautop in your theme's functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

However, this might screw up your content elsewhere on your site.

**Option 3.** Use yet another plugin, to toggle wpautop on or off of specific pages: https://wordpress.org/plugins/toggle-wpautop/

**Option 4.** Add some more shortcode attributes, then apply the required html via PHP, so you don't have to deal with this!

Comment: I tried using html directly in PHP code, and that worked. I've also tried the plugin you suggested and that solved the issue. Thanks a lot!